# How to get the height of UITableView that is bigger than the screen (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView that is larger than the screen height, and has dynamically sized cells (UITableViewAutomaticDimension).  I'm getting the height of the tableview the following way:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
let tableHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height
```

However, this height isnt always correct, especially for long lists with cells of drastically different sizes.  It seems to just take the table's estimated height and multiplies it by the number of rows.

How do you get the exact height of a tableView that has different cells?

Comment: I think you can use the code you have to get it - just need to query for it after it's drawn on the screen.

Comment: The whole idea of using estimated size is so that UITableView doesn't have to calculate its content size, because in order to do that it has to calculate the height of each and every cell. If you have hundreds or thousands of dynamically sized cells it gets super expensive to do that (especially when you rely on auto layout to size your cells). That's why you can't get the actual size in this case.

Comment: i figured. i guess ill manually calculate the cell heights on a background thread and update the tableview accordingly

Comment: @JoshO'Connor What are you trying to do? Why do you need to know contentSize? Also, how are you going to calculate UI stuff on the background thread?

Answer (score 0):

i had to create a method to detect when the bottom of the tableview was hit and reload the tableview, it was the only solution.

rule of thumb, try not to nest dynamically sized tableviews inside a scrollview.